# Scala.js - How to show browser alert?

Tags: scala.js

How to show a browser alert window in `Scala.js`? `JavaScript` version is as follows:

```
alert()
alert(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `scala-js-dom`:

```scala
import org.scalajs.dom.window.alert

alert("Hello Scala.js")
```